# Best practice git Module

Tags: git, git-submodules, subproject

In our git project we have one submodule. This submodule is configured in submodules file with a specific branch. So if we `init` or `update` the submodule, we always use the `--remote` Option.

But now, every time we update the submodule, there are changes in metadata of the submodule (subproject commit). The hash changes.

Is it possible to deactivate this change and just use the branch specified in gitmodules? In our case the commit hash is obsolete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+track+branch

Comment: My Problem is That i dont want to commit The sha1 of The submodule. Is it possible to just use The branch in gitmodules?

Comment: No. You always track a commit (by its id). By using the `--remote` option, the tracked id gets updated to the specified branches' current head, but you still have to commit the ID change in the main repository.

Comment: @kowsky thank you!